# Finding the minimum number of tours to cover all nodes

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am facing the below problem.

Statement:

1. A number of nodes with their locations are given
2. There is a central node in the middle which its location is also provided.
3. A route is defined as a path that starts from the central node and visits at least one node and ends up again in the central node.
4. Routes length must be shorter than a given number.

How do I cover all nodes with minimum number of routes?

I would appreciate any help that can provide a solution for this or a similar and famous problem that looks like this if there is anything.

Comment: What is the scale of the graph? Do you need an exact solution? This problem is NP-Complete with a simple reduction to Traveling Salesman Problem.

Comment: that would be great if i can see your algorithm in a pseudocode.and also how can i reduce it to TSP. cheers

Comment: I meant reduction from TSP, sorry. The problem is NP-Complete, so there is no known polynomial solution to it, but if the graph is fairly small - you can try brute force search.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Amit. I’m actually writing a paper and before using any heuristic algorithm i need to first proof that this problem is NP with showing its relation to TSP or any other famous NP algorithm. Do you know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with a simple reduction from [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).**

First, define the language that is accepted by this problem

```
L = { (G,x,i) | graph G, maximum length per path x, minimal number of travels required i }
```

It is easy to see that your problem is basically the optimization problem for the existence problem as defined above.

**TSP:**

Given an instance of TSP in the form of `(G,x)`, we need to determine if there is a cyclic path that goes through all points of length shorter/equals `x`.

**The reduction:**

The reduction is as follows. Given an instance of TSP `(G,x)`, provide the instance for your problem `(G,x,1)`.

**Correctness:**

- If there is a cyclic path that goes through all points of length `x`
  or less in the solution of TSP, there is also a solution to your
  problem with 1 travel required.
- If there is 1 travel required in the problem with length x or less, this is the route found by TSP.

The reduction we proposed is trivially polynomial.

From this we can conclude that your problem is NP-Hard, since TSP is NP-Hard.